# Selected Node Changed event not firing in the Treeview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, treeview

I have a `tree view` in a bootstrap `modal popup` body with `OnTreeNodeCheckChanged`.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Messages</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All" OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="TreeView1_TreeNodeCheckChanged">
                        </asp:TreeView>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The script is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function openModal() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    </script>
```

I have a `button` and when the button is clicked the popup with the tree view is displayed

```
       protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Fruits", "Fruits"));
            TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Mango", "Mango"));
            TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Apple", "Apple"));
            TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Pineapple", "Pineapple"));
            TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Orange", "Orange"));
            TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Grapes", "Grapes"));

            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Vegetables", "Vegetables"));
            TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Carrot", "Carrot"));
            TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Cauliflower", "Cauliflower"));
            TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Potato", "Potato"));
            TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Tomato", "Tomato"));
            TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Onion", "Onion"));

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
        }
```

When the `nodes` are checked `OnTreeNodeCheckChanged` event is not firing.When I close the popup and again click the button then the event is `OnTreeNodeCheckChanged` firing, i.e., the event is firing only when the buton is clicked twice.

What am I doing wrong, the event is not firing for the first time